# Views and message error Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed

Tags: sql-server

I have created the following view;

```
CREATE VIEW Artist_by_Rank
AS
    SELECT Artist, Genre FROM Artists
    UNION
    SELECT Artist, Change FROM Albums
```

The result was command created successfully.

When I try to see this view by using `SELECT * FROM Artist_by_Rank`, I get the following message

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Pop' to data type int.

`Pop` is a text which is part of the column `Genre`.

After this message, I checked the data type of the columns in the view which are

```
Artist (varchar(60), not null)
Genre (int, not null)
```

So to correct the error, I am trying to change the column `Genre` from `int` to `varchar`, but I get an error as follows;

```
ALTER VIEW Artist_by_Rank
CAST(Genre as varchar(15))
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Artist_by_Rank, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'

Comment: That is not a valid view definition...

Comment: You don't want 2 selects, probably a join?

Comment: You can not have multiple select statement in a view at first.

Comment: CREATE VIEW Artist_by_Rank
AS
SELECT A.Artist, Genre,Change   FROM Artists A JOIN Albums AL ON A.Artist = Al.Artist

Comment: Apologies, Mark is correct, it was not a valid view definition. I have edited for where my typo was in the create view statement, I did not included the word UNION in my statement. Hopefully, this edit makes my question clear and I get some clarification around my question. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a UNION here. UNION merges the results of two different queries. Obviously the results must have the same names and types. Do you really want to display `Change` in a column called `Genre`?

Comment: Change is just a name of a column in the table albums. This table has the columns Place2014 (ranking of the album for 2014 which is 1,2 reflecting first, second in the data etc); artist  (name); album (name); year (album was produced); place2008 (ranking for year 2008, similar to place2014) and change (which is the computed difference between the ranking for 2014 and 2008. I need to create a view  that will show artist, genre and highest ranking album.  Hence the above code.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER VIEW` doesn't work incrementally, you have to recreate the entire view the way you want, like:

```
CREATE VIEW Artist_by_Rank
AS
    SELECT Artist, CAST(Genre as varchar(15)) as Genre_char FROM Artists
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Artist, Change FROM Albums
```

sorry, try aliasing the result of the cast to a different name and see if the data type assignment sticks.  If it does, you can run it again with the alias you want (change genre_char to genre)

Comment: I tried this code, I had to add Genre after CAST(Genre as varchar(15)). The view created successfully but I got the same error message as above re the genre being int, so the Genre did not change to varchar. I have re-checked the code I put into SQL for any typo errors and there are none. Thanks